Pass Parameters/Values from Pipeline into Power Query Activity in ADF
I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to pass parameter/any values from my Azure Data Factory Pipeline into a Power Query Activity.
End goal is to dynamically reference different paths on the same dataset within my Power Query activity, but I'm running into dead ends.
I've attempted to create a parameter within the power query activity.
I've attempted to refence pipeline parameters as the value for the M query parameter.


Currently, parameters are not supported in the ADF power query. The above shown parameters are used only within the power query but there are no parameters for passing the values from ADF pipeline to this.
The only parameters that we can pass to a Power Query activity are the dataset parameters. You can see it has only dataset parameters unlike the dataflow.

In the Power Query activity also, there is no parameters section like dataflow. You can see it is taking only the dataset parameters.

You can raise a feature request for this here.
As a workaround, you can create a file for the required values and parameters and access those using dataset. Check this ask by @markwclancy to know more about this method.
